# How to play text to speech using xamarin.essential

Tags: forms, xamarin

I want to play text to speech but I can't hear anything using Xamarin.essential. I 'm sure I don't have muted smartphone. The code:

```
    using Xamarin.Essential


   private void PlayTextMethod()
   {
     if(do sth)
     {
      SpeekFrommethodAsync();
     }

   }

    
    private async SpeekFrommethodAsync()
    {
        await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync(Tasklabel.Text, new SpeechOptions
        {
            Volume = 1f
        });
    }
```

Comment: what platform are you testing on?  Have you followed any platform specific setup?

Comment: The platform is android

Comment: android a52 galaxy

Comment: external device

Comment: not pc emulator

Comment: did you follow the Android specific setup instructions in the docs?

Comment: yes of course I saw also the movie and I dont hear anything

Comment: have you tried hardcoded text like "Hello"?

Comment: Yes my android version is 12.0 I don't need set up for this versin in file Android.Manifest.xaml

Answer (score 0):

If your project's Target Android version is set to Android 11 (R API 30),
Open the AndroidManifest.xml file under the Properties folder and add the following inside of the manifest node:

```
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

And try this in your method:

```
 public async Task SpeakNow()
 {
   var locales = await TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();

   // Grab the first locale
   var locale = locales.FirstOrDefault();

   var settings = new SpeechOptions()
    {
        Volume = .75f,
        Pitch = 1.0f,
        Locale = locale
    };

   await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync("Hello World", settings);
 }
```

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/text-to-speech?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android

Comment: I've got android 12.0

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo and I tested it on the Android 12 emulator. I found the `Text-to-speech` function can not speak the words which belong to another country. So I added a picker to choose the country.

Here is the code in MainPage.xaml

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Text to speech sample!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Picker x:Name="Languages"></Picker>
        <Entry x:Name="TextToSpeak"></Entry>
        <Button Text="Speak Please" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

And here is the code in MainPage.xaml.cs.

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        IEnumerable<Locale> locales;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            locales = await TextToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();

            // add the locales to the picker
            foreach(var locale in locales)
            {
                Languages.Items.Add(locale.Name);
            }
                

        }

       // realize the button
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Languages.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
               
                // use the TextToSpeech to read the words in the Entry.
                TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync(TextToSpeak.Text, new SpeechOptions
                {
                    Locale = locales.Single(locales=> locales.Name == Languages.SelectedItem.ToString())
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the view of the project.

[image]